# convert pandas Series with large integer strings and Nones to nullable Int64 without precision loss

Tags: pandas, nullable, int64

I have a pandas Series with large integers as strings and Nones, and want to convert this to pandas Int64 (nullable integer) without precision loss. Casting to float (what e.g. pd.to_numeric does) leads to precision loss. What is a good way to do that?

E.g.

```
test_series = pd.Series(['4498465375688747025',
'4366843671738038466',
None,
None,
'4235221967816327545'])
```

`test_series.astype('Int64')` throws `TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype` on pandas 1.0.5

Comment: *pd.Series([int(x) if x else x for x in test_series], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())*
this works (see nullable integer in pandas doc) but I bet it is possible without list comprehension, looking into it